# How to load csv file from blob storage to azure sql database without Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, csv, azure-sql-database

**Environment** - MS Azure |
**Source** - Azure Blob Container (multiple CSV files saved in a folder).|
**Target** - Azure SQL Database.

My blob container receives multiple CSV files every day. I want to load all these CSV file data to the Azure SQL database. If the source data matches the target it should be updated, else it should be inserted. Once the data is loaded in the Azure SQL database, the CSV file has to be archived in the blob's different directory.  I have already done this work in Azure Data Factory, but now I want to work without Azure Data Factory like the Bulk Insert method or something else.

Is it possible to accomplish this without Azure Data Factory?

**CSV File Data Sample:**  - (csv file has no header)

```
1,Peter,35        
2,John,28  
3,Tony,24
```

Comment: Have a look at this answer.  Did it not come up on your google search?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/64423560/1527504

Answer (score 0):

> **Load csv file from blob storage to azure sql database**

***Follow these steps:***

**Step1:** Created database credentials and verify blob storage using SAS token

```
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL
['https://<storage_account_name>.blob.core.windows.net/<container name>/]
   
WITH IDENTITY = 'SAS Token',
SECRET = 'sv….;
```

**Step 2:** Create external data source

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE AzureStorage
WITH ( TYPE = BLOB_STORAGE,
          LOCATION = 'https://<storage_account_name>.blob.core.windows.net/',
          CREDENTIAL= ['https://<storage_account_name>.blob.core.windows.net/<container name>/]
);
```

**Step3:** BULK INSERT into import the CSV file

```
BULK INSERT samples.table1
FROM 'table1.csv'
WITH (DATA_SOURCE = 'AzureStorage',
    FIRSTROW = 2,
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ‘'
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'   
);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! But my question is to load the multiple files dynamically based on storage events Like Azure Data Factory. Once when the blob is created the data should be automatically loaded into the Azure SQL database. In that case, we can't set the file name as static and I am struggling to resolve that problem.

Comment: article is a weird polish website

Comment: @wordsforthewise Yes, looks like the original website is gone and all we can see now is a domain registration/hosting company's promotion.